# Angular web bluetooth write and notify example

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

Currently i'm working with this module for angular: [Angular web bluetooth](https://github.com/manekinekko/angular-web-bluetooth)

I can find an example how to read characteristics and got it working. But there are no samples to write (or notify). I am pretty sure that this module is capable of this tasks, [see here](https://manekinekko.github.io/angular-web-bluetooth/injectables/BluetoothCore.html), but my knowledge of Angular (or even JS?) isnt enough.

Did someone have any idea where to find examples or/and can provide them?

Snippet to read battery level:

```
getBatteryLevel() {
console.log('Getting Battery Service...');

try {
  return this.ble
    .discover$({
      acceptAllDevices: true,
      optionalServices: [BatteryLevelService.GATT_PRIMARY_SERVICE]
    })
    .mergeMap((gatt: BluetoothRemoteGATTServer) => {
      return this.ble.getPrimaryService$(
        gatt,
        BatteryLevelService.GATT_PRIMARY_SERVICE
      );
    })
    .mergeMap((primaryService: BluetoothRemoteGATTService) => {
      return this.ble.getCharacteristic$(
        primaryService,
        BatteryLevelService.GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_BATTERY_LEVEL
      );
    })
    .mergeMap((characteristic: BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic) => {
      return this.ble.readValue$(characteristic);
    })
    .map((value: DataView) => value.getUint8(0));
} catch (e) {
  console.error('Oops! can not read value from %s');
}
```

}

Thank you.

Edit: thanks to the assistance of Aluan Haddad i was able to perform a write request, with the right Service and Characteristic UUID

```
            .mergeMap((characteristic: BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic) => {
            let value = new Uint8Array(1);
            value[0] = 2;
          return this.ble.writeValue$(characteristic, value);
        }).subscribe();
```

Comment: Where's your attempted solution?

Comment: Ohh yes sorry. Like already mentioned, im pretty new to the whole web-thing. My attempted solution was to cut the last .map() away, let value = new Uint8Array(1); value[0] = 1; and return this.ble.writeValue$(characteristic, value). All more guessing than knowledge, but obviously its not the way how this works.

Comment: I'm afraid no one will help you if you don't try to solve the problem yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: I am fully your opinion and that was not my intention, to have anyone else write my code! The topic (bluetooth in web app environment) is pretty interesting and i tried different approches but in the angular context there is not much to find yet(except this module). Only hoped for a little hint, that would help me to understand this particular case.

Comment: I think you just need to write something like  `this.ble.writeValue(BatteryLevelService.GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_BATTERY_LEVEL, new UInt8Array(...)).subscribe(() => console.info('write succeeded'), () => console.error('write failed'));`. Does that help?

Comment: Wow, thanks for your patience! That was the kind of hint im talking about :) Think the way to notify isnt far. Updated initial question.